# Finding a lipschitz constant for an interval in a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to approach a question and my grasp on Lipschitz is a little rusty. My approach will be to take the max norm of the jacobian for my system and to set that as my constant.

My ODE is $\ y''(t) - \dfrac{g}l\sin(y(t))$ with g being the gravitational constant and l being a constant. I've re-written this as a system of linear ODEs.

$\ w(t)$ denotes $\ y'(t)$

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}w(t)\\-\frac{g}l\sin(y(t))\end{array}\right]$$

I would then take the jacobian and get:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-\frac{g}l\cos(y(t))&0\end{array}\right]$$

From here, do I just need to show that my constant will be $\max(1, (-g/l)\cos(y(t))) $ in the interval?

Comment: is this a pendulum?

Comment: You need to compute a bound on $\| \frac{\partial f(x)} {\partial x} \|$, this wlll serve as your Lipschitz constant using the mean value theorem.

Comment: Yes this is a general pendulum